# how to bulid table with borders from csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

i got csv file that looks like this :

```
indiv_number,genename,to_append
0,gene1,[000011]
0,gene2,[101010]
0,gene3,[0101010]
1,gene1,[0101010]
1,gene2,[0101010]
```

I want it to look like this :

```
                gene1       gene2       gene3 
indiv_number 

0             [000011]    [101010]     [0101010]
1             [0101010]   [0000]       [010101]
3             [1010101]    [01010]     [00011]
```

how it's possible to do this

Comment: If you used `pandas.to_csv(filename)` you need to open it with a program that can render comma separated values (like excel or libre office). Your first output is a valid csv file but it looks like you opened it with a regular text editor like notepad..

Comment: do you notice the difference between the two tables they don't look alike I need to convert things from column into row wich means the second column from csv is the header in the second

Comment: you did not mention at all how you got those outputs. Please check guidelines for asking questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the first output is something related to my imagination none of them are real, the concept is how to convert between the tables or how to change csv file into a table like the second structure

Answer (score 0):

First use [pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to convert your dataframe to the desired structure. Then use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to save it with header and index (column and row names).

Comment: I already did this step, but when trying to display the output of the df that is saved to csv everything is mixed